# .Net Core Entity Framework 6 Nested Transaction Architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Entity framework doesn't support nested transactions, so how can nested services update data with a failsafe such is a transaction?

Scenario: A has 1-to-* relationship with B. By default B needs to be created when A is created, but A is not a required field.

**
Service A
**

```
public void CreateA(A a)
{

    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        _context.Alist.Add(a);

        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }

        try
        {
            var newB = new B
            {
                AId = a.Id,
                Name = "Default"
            };
            Bservice.Create(newB);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

**
Service B
**

```
public void CreateB(B b)
{
    _context.Blist.Add(b);

    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly well as expected, however, new requirement comes in: C table needs to be implemented and has *-to-1 relationship with B. By default C needs to be created when B is created. User can create B without creating A, and C without creating B or A.

So, naturally, as C is the lowest level, can be created by itself and live on it's own, code base can be as simple as:

```
public void CreateC(C c)
{
    _context.Clist.Add(c);

    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

So the question is, what becomes of B? If B is being created, then it should look exactly as A, creating B and a default C through a transaction. However, this would not work if the method is called through A service due to nested transactions issue. Alternatively, leaving it as is and just adding creation of C is incorrect since if B is being created by itself as it will not catch an exception if thrown in the C service. Is the only way to achieve this is to have 2 separate methods for deletion with and without a transaction? Passing down a transaction is also not an option, as a very least it makes code extremely ugly.

This simple example should portray the issue.

Looking forward to suggestions.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: The very idea is wrong. The code breaks EF's transaction model. In EF the DbContext is a Unit-of-Work container. All changes are tracked and nothing is persisted until `SaveChanges` is called *at the very end of a unit of work* to *commit* all changes in a single transaction. EF doesn't even keep a connection open until this point. There's *no* reason to start a transaction

Comment: EF depends on *optimistic* concurrency (ie no transactions) to find out if the stored data has changed between the time it was first loaded and the time changes were committed with SaveChanges. At this point, the generated SQL statements will check if the rows match the loaded data and throw a concurrency exception if they changed. This is *orders of magnitude* more scalable than using explicit transactions, because it doesn't cause blocks. This is why it's used since the early 2000s and inherently supported in both ADO.NET DataTables and EF.

Comment: In your case the *proper* way is to create the DbContext in a `using` block, add any entities you want to it and only call `SaveChanges` once right before the `using` block ends. This way, even in case of errors the DbContext will be disposed and all changes will be discarded

Comment: . PS: `catch(Exception exc){ throw ex;}` is a bug as well. It doesn't offer *any* benefit but it *does* erase the stack trace of the original exception, making it harder to debug. It also incurs the cost of throwing another exception. It would be better to not catch the exception at all. If you want to log and rethrow use `throw;`. This will reraise the original exception without modification

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for quick responses. To address your comment on using context: Services in this scenario are configured as Scoped, so they use the same context through DI. It is understandable that changes are only committed on save changes, but using examples above, same issue would happen. You will then have to have 2 create methods for B. One, that creates B and C and saves changes at the end, and another that creates B and C, but doesn't save changes as changes to be saved in A service. I hope this helps.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I appreciate your comment on Exceptions and you are correct. In this post code is only used as sample, but I will definitely be mindful in production.

Comment: This means the services shouldn't be designed this way. A DbContext is a UoW, Period. Your services *depend* on each other, even if that's indirectly through the DI and the scoped DbContext. That's wrong. Use a *single* service instead. Pass the context as a parameter method to the other services. If the root is eg a Controller Action just pass the controller's DbContext to the service methods

Comment: You should probably rename the classes because they aren't really services. The name `service` implies some sort of autonomy. That's not the case here. These classes seem to act as single-entity "repositories". A DbSet is a single-entity repository though, which is why the methods you posted seem to be just aliases for `DbSet.Add`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if I understand you correctly, you are suggesting to only saving changes in the top level consistently, which could be a controller instead of passing the responsibility of saving down? This would certainly resolve the issue at hand..

Comment: Yes, that's how DbContext is designed to work. That's why you don't see explicit transactions in any docs, course or tutorial. Only in SO questions asking "Why do my transactions fail?"

Answer (score 2):

Your Transaction is in the wrong scope.  It should be in the outermost scope.  eg

Assuming each service runs its own SaveChanges() and has the same scoped DbContext instance injected, then:

```
 using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
 {
   _serviceA.CreateA(a);
   _serviceB.CreateB(b);
   _serviceC.CreateC(c);
   transaction.Commit();
 }
```

There are times when you must defer SaveChanges because of database relationships, but that's really a seperate issue.

Comment: Thanks for response, but this wouldn't make sense directly creating child and a grandchild in the outmost top component. Codebase would require duplication of the codebase, when only B and C are required to be created without an A. However, deferral of save changes, as per your comment and one of the responses above, is the way to go for this specific example. If the logic and processing done in the lower components and saving always done in the top one, which is a Controller in this scenario, it would work. However, this kind of breaks repository pattern in terms of saving, as a very least.

Comment: The DbContext is your repository, not the individual services that share a DbContext instance.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution in entity framework core 3.1 .

1. Implement IDbContextTransactionManager: calculate scopes when BeginTransaction or CommitTransaction are called, and do real BeginTransaction and CommitTransaction in the outmost scope.

```
public class NestedTransactionManager : IDbContextTransactionManager
{
    readonly ISqlServerConnection _sqlServerConnection;

    public NestedTransactionManager(ISqlServerConnection sqlServerConnection)
    {
        // Dependency inject ISqlServerConnection, ISqlServerConnection is original IDbContextTransactionManager in EF Core 3.1 .
        _sqlServerConnection = sqlServerConnection;
    }

    int Layer = 0;

    public IDbContextTransaction CurrentTransaction
        => _sqlServerConnection.CurrentTransaction;

    public IDbContextTransaction BeginTransaction()
    {
        if (Layer++ == 0)
            _sqlServerConnection.BeginTransaction();
        return new NestedTransation(this, Layer);
    }

    public async Task<IDbContextTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (Layer++ == 0)
            await _sqlServerConnection.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);
        return new NestedTransation(this, Layer);
    }

    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
        if (Layer-- <= 1)
            _sqlServerConnection.CommitTransaction();
    }

    public Task CommitTransactionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => Layer-- <= 1
        ? _sqlServerConnection.CurrentTransaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken)
        : Task.CompletedTask;
        
    public void ResetState()
        => _sqlServerConnection.ResetState();

    public Task ResetStateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => _sqlServerConnection.ResetStateAsync(cancellationToken);

    public void RollbackTransaction()
        => _sqlServerConnection.RollbackTransaction();
}
```

```
class NestedTransation : IDbContextTransaction
{
    readonly NestedTransactionManager _manager;

    readonly int _layer;

    public NestedTransation(NestedTransactionManager manager, int layer)
    {
        _manager = manager;
        _layer = layer;
    }

    bool Commited => _layer > _manager.Layer;

    public Guid TransactionId
        => Transaction.TransactionId;

    IDbContextTransaction Transaction
        => _manager.CurrentTransaction;

    public void Commit()
        => _manager.CommitTransaction();

    public Task CommitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => _manager.CommitTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!Commited && Transaction != null)
            Transaction.Dispose();
    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        => !Commited && Transaction != null
        ? Transaction.DisposeAsync()
        : default;

    public void Rollback()
        => Transaction.Rollback();

    public Task RollbackAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => Transaction.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

2. Replace service in Startup

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.ReplaceService<IDbContextTransactionManager, NestedTransactionManager>();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this...

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // ....

    public async Task UsingTransaction(Func<Task> asyncAction)
    {
        if (Database.CurrentTransaction != null)
        {
            await asyncAction();
        }
        else
        {
            using (var transaction = Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    await asyncAction();
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so I call it in code like this...

```
await _context.UsingTransaction(async () => {

    // ...
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // ...
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

});
```

ps. it is advised that you also create an overload for synchronous code...

```
public void UsingTransaction(Action action)
{
   //... sync code
}
```